# WEBLOGIC ADF 12.2.1.3 - Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbo.service.helper.SDOAnnotationProvider

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c

here we have a problem with weblogic 12.2.1.3.0, when we try to deploy ADF Application 12.2.1.3.0, it's throws this message below:

```
06:02:28 PM] Deploying 1 data source(s) to the server...

[06:02:28 PM] Deploying Application...

[06:02:39 PM] [Deployer:149192]Operation "deploy" on application "mdblog" is in progress on "DefaultServer".

[06:02:42 PM] [Deployer:149193]Operation "deploy" on application "mdblog" has failed on "DefaultServer".

[06:02:42 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application mdblog on DefaultServer.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbo.service.helper.SDOAnnotationProvider.

[06:02:42 PM] weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbo.service.helper.SDOAnnotationProvider

[06:02:42 PM] Deployment cancelled.

[06:02:42 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
```

We tried to find this library on internet, but unsuccess.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Hi,

I found a way to do this deploy, without error, the problem hapened when use ".war" to deploy, I just a build a deploy as  ".ear"  file and work's fine.

 

But can't found a way to deploy as .war.

Comment: I guess first of all thanks for letting us know, and you can also post a answer to your question if you think thats the solution